# What is the acceptable event rate to use ROC-AUC instead of precision-recall curve?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc, precision-recall, unbalanced-classes

It says [here](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/icml2006_DavisG06.pdf)

> However, when dealing with highly skewed datasets, Precision-Recall (PR) curves give a more informative picture of an algorithm's performance.

My question is;

What is the common definition of "highly-skewed". Is 10% positive and 90% negative a highly skewed dataset?

Comment: It's not highly skewed but PR curves would already be useful in that case. It mainly depends on what you actually want to do (e.g., model selection).